# Woocommerce - “Consumer Key is invalid”

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm getting a JSON object result in POSTMAN, but in browser it is showing “Consumer Key is invalid”.

Result in Postman:

[image]

Error in Browser:

[image]

Please help me out of this. Thanks.